# Can MT4 send an email, when a trade S/L is triggered, as an example?

Tags: mt4

Morning all,

Just wanting to ask, is it possible to be able to send an email with the outcome of your trade details ( i.e. your loss, trade number and account number ) when your S/L is triggered?

I know this will need to be achieved through the `OrderSelect()` function with the `MODE_HISTORY`.

Also, I want to be clear, I'm not asking anybody to write the code for me, I know this isn't a "charity site" but just wanted to now if it were possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, that is perfectly possible.

1. **ENABLE** sending emails in MetaTrader Terminal 4 settings, incl. target ( constant ) address
   [image]
2. **CLICK** <kbd>Test</kbd> to send a testing-message, to have an End-to-End email PASS / FAIL proof
3. **DESIGN** a "sender"-factory as **`void notifyByEMAIL( const string InfSTRING ){...}`** as flexible as you wish to have, using `SendMail( aSubjectSTR, aBodySTR );`
4. **DESIGN** a "scanner"-utility function, embedding the XTO-domain event-scans ( with some built-in self-integrity and persistence tools, not to report the same XTO-event next time etc. ), re-using the sender-factory:
    `void scanRecentXtoEventsToNOTIFY(){... /*notifyByEMAIL( anEventDETAILs );*/ ... }`